# HTML - Mails don't look right after they got send (thunderbird)

Tags: html, email, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm currently making an E-Mail for Christmas Greetings. When I send the Mail or put it in "Drafts" he doesnt show the Mail correct.

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWhsN.jpg)

[How it looks in reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjuTS.png)

I am using WYSIWYG Web Builder 9

You can find the HTML code in the comments.

Comment: Here the HTML-Code which I pasted in the E-Mail: http://pastebin.com/AGjtcbEq

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to tweak and test the HTML until it works the way you want it to in Thunderbird.

I'd highly suggest using an email testing tool, such as [Email On Acid](https://www.emailonacid.com/) or [Mandrill](https://litmus.com/) to test your HTML in less common and dated clients.

HTML emails are painful to code, but it is getting better slowly :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would suggest not using div's in email.
Stick with table's, tr's and td's.

Background images in email aren't well supported on desktop email clients like Outlook. Mobile support is great however!
You will need to use this site: http://backgrounds.cm/ to give you a hack to get support in almost all email clients...

Try to remember html email is like coding websites in 1999. It's old school and a pain!

If you get stuck, let me know.
I'm an email developer by trade, and would be happy to give you a reasonable quote to fix this up.